# Tic tac toe gameboard values are not changing

Tags: c++

So I have problem with changing the values with function setAlls in functions.h . I do not understand why this function will not work, but when I call method in Gameboard.cpp, which will do the same kind of think, this will change the values. And I have one more question. Exactly when create .h and when .cpp and what place inside them. I read about this topic on forum, so .h is using for declaration and .cpp for definition. But sometimes i see using .cpp for both and sometimes .h . I am doing course on udacity on C++ and there for this tic tac toe are just 3 .cpp files for work online without need for local compiler on pc. But when i work there it will pop up class redefinition error and I do not know really why. Can someone plese help me with this ?

## Source.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "Gameboard.h"

int main() {
    Gameboard gameboard;
    gameboard.setPointAll('x');
    gameboard.printBoard();
    setAlls(gameboard,'h');
    gameboard.printBoard();
    return 0;
}
```

## Gameboard.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Gameboard
{
    char board[4][4];

public:
    Gameboard();
    void setPoint(int row, int column, char pointIn);
    void setPointAll(char pointIn);
    char getPoint(int row, int column);
    //int lookingForX();
    //int lookingForO();
    void printBoard();
};
```

## Gameboard.cpp

```
#include "Gameboard.h"

Gameboard::Gameboard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}
void Gameboard::printBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j];
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
void Gameboard::setPoint(int row, int column, char pointIn) {
    board[row][column] = pointIn;
}
void Gameboard::setPointAll(char pointIn) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            board[i][j] = pointIn;
        }
    }
}
char Gameboard::getPoint(int row, int column) {
    return board[row][column];
}
#include "Gameboard.h"

Gameboard::Gameboard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}
void Gameboard::printBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j];
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
void Gameboard::setPoint(int row, int column, char pointIn) {
    board[row][column] = pointIn;
}
void Gameboard::setPointAll(char pointIn) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            board[i][j] = pointIn;
        }
    }
}
char Gameboard::getPoint(int row, int column) {
    return board[row][column];
```

## functions.h

```
#include "Gameboard.h"

void setAlls(Gameboard gameboard, char value);


void setAlls(Gameboard gameboard, char value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            gameboard.setPoint(i, j, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the function to change the values stored in a variable, why are you passing a copy of it, and not a reference to it?

Comment: Nice this is working, thank you very much :D I forgot on this. And the .h vs .cpp difference ?